# How to achieve Android's getViewById in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

IOS's `IBOutlet` is fine in most scenarios. But consider this:

I have a `UITableview` which contains 2 types of custom cells, both cells have the same subviews (1 image view and 2 labels), only the 2 types layout differently. Now how do I reference these subviews in my code?

I could, of course, define 2 subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, and use IBOutlet to reference them. But that sounds not very elegant, as behavior-wise, they are exactly the same.

Android has a `getViewById` function. In iOS, can I get a subview from a view with some identifier?

Comment: yes, we can use viewWithTag function

Comment: this is embarrassing, I should have looked up doc first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give tag values to these subviews and you can get these subviews by using viewWithTag function. For example in swift for say label with tag 100 you can use

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel
    label?.text = "label from tag"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your situation, the elegant solution is to define two cells with different layout in TableView in a Storyboard, or in two Xib files. And then, binding them to the same class.

The separated cell defined in Storyboard or Xib means the same thing in Android: separated layout XML files, which you want to access its sub view by `getViewById`.